# TFS 2015 On-prem: web extension failing to load over https - (The request is not supported)

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I need specific guidance about when using a TFS web extension while the TFS instance is exposed over internet using ***https*** protocol.

Background: I developed a **TFS 2015 web extension** using rest api and installed it on our tfs collection using tfs-cli.

After installation and enabling the extension I load this extension; it throws the following error

> “Error Code: 500 Internal Server Error. The request is not supported.
>   (50)”.

During analysis I discovered that the issue is related to our TFS configuration over http and https.

*I am experiencing the same error for other 3rd party extensions like [FolderManagement](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.FolderManagement) and [Team Calendar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.team-calendar) over **https**. These extensions work great in our TFS 2015 lab environment which is only exposed over **http** on the domain.*

---

*Let’s take example of the *FolderManagement* extension available in the marketplace.*

**Attempt 1 - previous configuration:**

We have an external url say `https://tfs.companyname.com/tfs` registered in TMG which was routing all traffic to our internal TFS instance say `http://machinename:port/tfs`

In TFS Admin console notification url was set to `https://tfs.companyname.com/tfs`

*When we accessed extension in TFS web, it didn’t load and in browser debug we got following error:*

> GET
>   `https://tfs.companyname.com/tfs/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/ms-devlabs/extension/FolderManagement/1.1.10/assetbyname/main.html`
>   “Error Code: 500 Internal Server Error. The request is not supported.
>   (50)”.

**Attempt 2:**

Then I changed TFS notification url in Admin console to point to internal instance `http://machinename:port/tfs`

Now all extensions started working fine when we accessed our TFS using `http://machinename:port/tfs`.

However when we accessed external url `https://tfs.companyname.com/tfs` then extensions didn’t work as TMG was forwarding traffic from secure (https) to insecure(http) and caused authorization issues.

**Attempt 3 - Current configuration:**

On TFS server we added https binding (port 443) to *“Team Foundation Server”* website and assigned valid certificate. Side note - The certificate is wildcarded `*.companyname.com` supporting the exposed dns entry for the site.

In the TFS Admin console, the notification url is set to `https://tfs.companyname.com/tfs`
 and server url is also set to `https://tfs.companyname.com/tfs`

External url `https://tfs.companyname.com/tfs` is routing traffic to TFS server (machine IP) over 443 port.

Now when we are accessing extension in TFS web, It’s showing same error as mentioned earlier i.e.

> GET
>   `https://tfs.companyname.com/tfs/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/ms-devlabs/extension/FolderManagement/1.1.10/assetbyname/main.html`
>   “Error Code: 500 Internal Server Error. The request is not supported.
>   (50)”.

Given the current configuration I am getting the same behaviour/error for both http and https.

**Question:** Why does the extension work as expected when all configuration is targeting a TFS installation hosted over http but when exposed over https the web extension behaves differently?

Comment: What's you TFS server url you are using? http or https？ Open the Team Foundation Server Administrator Console. Check the server url

Comment: I am using https url. In Team Foundation Sever administrator console server url is set to `https://tfs.companyname.com/tfs`. If possible I want to get TFS 2015 web extension working for both http and https url configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say both http and https can work well with the same configuration for the web extension is impossible. Try below configuration  before your deploy your web extension.

> Configuring Your Deployment to Require HTTPS with SSL (Optional)
>
> You can require all connections to the TFS application tier to use
>   HTTPS with SSL. This additional security is optional but recommended.
>
> To require SSL connections
>
> 1.On the server that hosts the website that you want to configure, choose Start, choose Administrative Tools, and then choose Internet
>   Information Services (IIS) Manager.
>
> 2.Follow the appropriate steps for your version of IIS:
>
> For deployments that use IIS 7.0:
>
> a.Expand ComputerName, expand Web Sites, and then choose the website
>   that you want to configure.
>
> b.On the home page for that website, choose SSL Settings.
>
> c.In the SSL Settings pane, select the Require SSL check box.
>
> (Optional) Select the Require 128-bit SSL check box.
>
> d.In Client Certificates, choose Ignore, Accept, or Require, depending
>   on the security requirements of your deployment.
>
> e.In Actions, choose Apply.
>
> f.Repeat these steps for each website for which you want to require
>   SSL.

More details about HTTPS with TFS please refer this MSDN  link : [Set up HTTPS with Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) for Team Foundation Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833872(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: Tried suggested solution but web extension is not working. Result is same as mentioned in question.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be TMG related issue. TFS configuration was correct.
Thanks a lot to everyone who helped. This issue can be closed now.

Comment: What is TMG?  (adding characters to fulfill ridiculous and arbitrary minimum-fifteen-character limit on comments)

Comment: TMG is MS threat management gateway. https://tmgblog.richardhicks.com/forefront-tmg/

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug in the product. For some strange reason (bad practice) whoever decided to write those image urls didn't honor the current browser url. This would be very simple if they just wrote a relative url.

In my case a have a public https url https://team.devscope.net/tfs/_api..., and an internal https://*:8080/tfs, but the product just invented an unprotected/new url named http://team.devscope.net:8080/tfs/_apis.

result is just an error in the browser:
[image]